# Raspberry Pi 3 first boot issues

Tags: boot-issues, ubuntu, pi-3

Just received the Pi 3 in the mail.  So I unplugged the Pi 2, took out the SD card from the 2 and put it in the 3. Connected everything from the Pi 2 on the 3 and attempted to boot.  The image is a Ubuntu Mate and works fine in the 2, so I assumed I could just move the SD card and external USB drive over to the 3 and boot.

What I get is a rainbow color selector pattern sort of display on my screen and it doesn't go any further.  Did I get a bad Pi 3 or are my assumptions about the image from my Pi 2 working in the 3 wrong?

To make sure that the sd card was still functioning I just put it back into the Pi 2 and booted.  So the image still appears to work.  Just strange that I don't get any text, or anything appear on the screen other than the rainbow color chooser looking screen.  No text, warnings, or anything usable appears.  Thanks for your feedback and help with this.

Comment: You need a recent kernel and recent boot files.  I have no idea how you achieve that with Ubuntu Mate.

Comment: I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally managed to achieve this.

Unfortunately the usual `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` does not upgrade the kernel beyond 4.1.13.

I ended up using `rpi-update` to update the firmware (to 4.1.20). Note that `rpi-update` is not normally used by normal users, as it can install beta software.

That produced an image which boots on the Pi3, but inbuilt WiFi did not work.

I finally managed to install WiFi firmware with

```
cd /lib/firmware/brcm/
sudo wget https://github.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree/raw/master/brcm80211/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin
sudo wget https://github.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree/raw/master/brcm80211/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt
```

There is a pre-built image which works on the Pi3 which can be dwnloaded from the MATE web site.

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee it will work, but do a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to get the latest kernel and modules and try it again.  It's been hit an miss on some other distros and the most reliable solution is to back up what you want to keep somewhere, wipe the card, and reload with the latest image.

Answer (score 0):

just update and upgrade PI2 it will work fine in pi3

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: More detail is required